# Can someone show me how to connect to a H2 database with ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, h2

I'm simply looking for some basic code examples showing me how to connect to a H2 database on the ColdFusion server and perhaps couple of examples of how to execute SQL statements.

Thanks.

Comment: read the tutorial - there's code given for how to connect to the database! http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html

Comment: Read the H2 tutorial Rachel provided, then read [this CF tutorial on queries](http://learncfinaweek.com/week1/Databases/), then - if you're unsure about anything, you can ask specific/targetted questions.

Comment: Thank you Rachel and Peter. I should've said I'm very familiar with ColdFusion but not so much with H2. Another developer in our company used a H2 database to use in a JAR file he wrote. The db file is located on the ColdFusion server. H2 tutorial talks about some H2 console, but we're not using it. As such, I don't believe I can connect to the db through CF Admin datasources. So, I was thinking I had to use H2 Java libraries to connect. This is the part I need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with H2, but from skimming the tutorial, I would say start by creating an ["other"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fe9.html) datasource. Then connect using [embedded mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes).

[These instructions](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/configure-jdbc-driver-mysql-4.html) are for the MySQL driver, but the same concepts apply to using any jdbc driver.

- [Download](http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html) and install the driver jar, and restart CF.
- Create a datasource of type "Other" and enter the appropriate:

  - [JDBC URL](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url)
  - [Driver class](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc)
  - Username and password

You can get the rest from [the documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html).